# Can a single false statement give rise to two separate causes of action i.e. counts in a lawsuit?

Tags: defamation, libel, civil

Is it possible under US libel for a single false statement to give rise to two separate causes of action (i.e. counts) in a lawsuit?

If the answer is yes, what would be some examples of this?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

I hire an engineer to give advice. The advice is:

- not what I contracted for - breach of contract
- negligent - tort of negligent misstatement
- not given with due skill and care - consumer protection warranty breach
- defamatory - libel
- late - breach of contract again
- disclosed to my competition - breach of confidence

The engineer was clearly on  a roll.

Comment: Thanks. I have rephrased my question based on this. I was referring only two separate counts of libel (not other legal causes of action).

Comment: @GillHamel please don’t rephrase questions to invalidate already given answers - ask another question. Questions are free.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes (the libel edition.)**

"Morgan and Robin are having an affair and cheating on their respective spouses!"

I hope it's clear enough, on its face, that both Morgan and Robin each have a cause of action.

Comment: But the question is "...in a lawsuit."  Would Morgan and Robin sue jointly?

Comment: @phoog I think so.  It makes absolutely no sense to argue about the same facts twice; there needs to be a single hearing.

Comment: If Morgan and Robin have plenty of money and can afford two lawsuits, couldn't Morgan go to court first, causing inconvenience and cost for the person libelling her, and when that case is over, Robin does the same?